# Mathematics Radical Numbers Problem

Tags: roots

If,

$$\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{\sqrt 2-1} = x $$

then,

$$\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{\sqrt 2+1} = ? $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $y=\frac{\sqrt 5-1}{\sqrt 2+1}$

$$\implies xy=\dfrac{5-1}{2-1}=?$$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Simplify the product of the two expressions.

Comment: Thank you but could you write down please